# Getting response when a background thread finishes its work

Tags: c#, .net, threadpool

How can you get some feedback from a thead started using the ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem method when it finishes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using a `BackgroundWorker` instead. That also uses the threadpool, and launches a seperate event (on the calling thread) when the background task is complete.

Otherwise you will have to do this manually by invoking a method manually on the main thread, but the `BackgroundWorker` encapsulates this in a very nice manner.